How can a system's overall transfer function be the same if the poles are different?
I am working through a problem that gives a block diagram representation of a physical variable state space. It then asks to build the state system for that physical variable system and a phase variable model. I reduced the given block diagram to a single i-o one and built the phase variable rep. Part 2 asks you to compute the eigenvalues of both matrices and test their sensitivity to change. The eigenvalues of the first matrix are s = .5 with a multiplicity of 2 and the eigenvalues of the phase variable rep are complex conjugates. How is this possible? The eigenvalues are in effect the poles of the system and both reps model the same plant so they should have the same poles, right?

Please show your work.
